# Netbeans x PHP : XDebug not working on OSX Sierra

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, osx-elcapitan

I just updated my Mac to Sierra and now XDebug does not work anymore in my Netbeans 8.0.2. When i click on 'Debut Project' button, the browser is loaded with my project, but my breakpoints does not work and the following message is shown on Netbeans bottom status bar :

Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)

Any hints how to fix this ? Everything was working fine before the update.

Thanks !

Comment: Plz update your post with the versions of tools and OS, for more clarity on your issue

Comment: Updated Netbeans version, OS version is already written in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the same thing happened to me, and I wound up reinstalling xdebug, which required updating Xcode to 8.0.

Sierra installs an updated version of PHP, so you'll probably have to reconfigure PHP.

In my case, I had a separate version of PHP installed, so after updating xdebug, I pointed Apache at that version. Since it was already configured to use xdebug, I didn't have to do anything else.

Comment: I can't manage to solve it anymore ; i edited my new PHP.INI with xdebug settings. Is there anything else i might try ? phpinfo() shows that xdebug is running, but i can't debug with Netbeans, same error message.

Answer (score 2):

you need to turn on xdebug.remote_enable in php.ini, some installer overwrite the php.ini settings.
Hope this help.

Comment: Yes, after i edited php.ini AND reboot the machine (only a apache restart was not enogh), it worked again, thanks :D

Comment: In my case, xdebug.remote_enable had definitely been turned off: turning it on and restarting apache worked fine. (@delphirules, I suspect you may have had more than one apache on your machine and restarted the wrong one, but that's just a guess.)